# SetWindowsHookEx returns with "Invalid window handle" since moving to .net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, pinvoke

Since moving to `.net 4.0` from `2.0`, I cannot run successfully the `SetWindowsHookEx` function. It always ends with the `Win32` error number `1400`: `"Invalid window handle"`.

This is the pinvoke signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookExA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, int hModule, int dwThreadId);
```

This is the call:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookProc, iModule, 0);
```

It worked before. Why should it return with an "Invalid window handle" error anyway ?

btw: on windows 7 it works, but only if I set iModule = 0. on XP it doesn't work anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem solved:

The problem was the iModule. I assigned it this way:

```
int iModule = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0])
).ToInt32();
```

And the right way to do that, is apparently:

```
int iModule = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
```

But I'll be glad to know the reason for that. Logically, the GetModules()[0] gives the dll file itself where the callback function resides, while GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress returns the main module (dll file ?), that may be different from the dll that holds the callback function.

So how come it actually works "the other way around" - according to my understanding ? and how come it worked until I changed the .net version ?